# Random special character with JS regex

Tags: javascript, regex, special-characters

I'm trying to use regular expressions in JS to return a random special character from a selection, for example ?, !, *, $.

I'm able to generate random *non*-special characters using the following code:

```
Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '').substr(0, 1);
```

However, I simply don't know how to make it return special characters.

I am of course aware of the need to escape special characters in the regex, but so far no combination of backslashes and/or slashes has produced the chracters (it always returns either whitespace or 0 in an alert). For example I tried something like:

```
Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^\?\!\$]+/g, '').substr(0, 1);
```

To be honest, I simply don't understand regular expressions well enough, the problem might be due to any number of things (maybe the 36 is wrong in this case?) and I would really appreciate if someone could give me some advice!

Comment: So, just those four special characters, or anything that isn't `a-z` in a random fashion ?

Comment: Note that `Math.random().toString(36)` doesn't generate special characters

Comment: those 4 were just  an example, basicly i would just like to be able to get a regex that returns a random special character of any set of characters that i choose, whether it is ($, §, *) or (?, #, &).

Comment: perhaps you should create an array of these special chars, then generate a random number to select a character by index?

Comment: You really should have been using `String.fromCharCode(97 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 26))` to generate standard characters, not that `toString(36)`+regex abomination.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't made clear why you want to use regexen to address your problem.

Adopting the idea from @sweaver2112's comment,try something like

```
function randomSpecialChar () {
    // example set of special chars as a string in no particular order
    var s = "!\"§$%&/()=?\u{20ac}";

    // generating a random index into the string and extracting the character at that position
    return s.substr(Math.floor(s.length*Math.random()), 1);
}
```

Comment: Shorthand: `const randomSpecialChar = () => "!\"§$%&/()=?\u{20ac}".substr(~~(12*Math.random()),1)`